# check if SPField exists using list services

Tags: 2007, column

I want to check if a custom field exists for my list using list services but not sure how I can do it, I know it can be done using object model method "ContainsField()" but how can I do same with services,

```
    public bool fieldExists()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
                    //field exists or not ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup you can look into hash table and find key you need for that field if it exists or not. I don't remember 100% the code I used but I will try to provide it someone need it in future.

Hope it helps if someone else came across same problem :)